# TransactionInDoubt" using System.Transactions, Appearantly in TransactionScope.Complete()

Tags: system.transactions

We have this problem in our system. We're using `System.Transactions` and work with `TransactionScope` (mostly, and definitely in this case). We've just migrated from `EnterpriseServices` to `SystemTransactions` recently, and we got this error several times, during heavy multi-threaded work:

`System.Transactions.TransactionInDoubtException: The transaction is in doubt. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment enlistment)`

It was apparently thrown during the `Scope.Complete()`.

I've read a bit about `TransactionInDoubt`, that it might happen in the promotion to `DTC`, and maybe there's a slight connectivity issue with the SQL, or the MSDTC. but then - what is with the Timeout Expired which is a `SqlException`?? where is the timeout exactly? in the commit???

I've been scanning the web for the past few days and some occurrences here and there, but no good answers.

help anyone??

Comment: I am also getting this error and searched on google but nothing concrete solution. Have you ever resolved it?